# FInding a HTML element from HTML source code

Tags: vb.net

so i am trying to find a HTML element which is:

```
<a class="signout" href="https://www.dreamstime.com/logout.php">Sign out</a>
```

my code is:

```
 Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

                If thepage.Contains("<a href="https: //www.dreamstime.com/logout.php" class="signout">Sign out</a>") Then
                    good += 1
                    Label2.Text = "Good: " & good.ToString

                    If pencil = False Then
                        TextBox1.Text += currentaccount & vbNewLine
                        Me.Refresh()
                    End If
```

but this error occurs every time:
[OPEN ME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeSgX.jpg)

i try to remove the space but it keeps appearing error says 
comma,")",or valid expression continuation expected.

Comment: You need to use double double-quotes inside a string. So `Dim s = "a""b"` will result in s being set to `a"b`.

Comment: @ Andrew Morton can you please apply this on my code? i am new to vb.net so its hard to understand you.

Comment: It would be like this: `If thepage.Contains("<a href=""https://www.dreamstime.com/logout.php"" class=""signout"">Sign out</a>") Then`

Comment: or maybe, little easier way : `Dim ahref As String = "<a class='signout' href='https://www.dreamstime.com/logout.php'>Sign out</a>".Replace("'", Chr(34))` and then `If thepage.Contains(ahref) Then ...` ... to not "lost" in so many double double-quotes. `Chr(34)` is ascii code for double-quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not properly escape the quotation mark. "A" = A, "" = , """" = "

OR lets use * so its easier to see,
*"**, first * for start, then " your character, then another * so it knows character ends, and * as end of string.

In longer string that would look like:

```
"some string ""is"" here"
```

This results in:

```
some string "is" here
```